# Andengine black screen

Tags: android, andengine

I am calling the games scene , scene loaded and i press back or home button. Then i start app again, after splash screen i am getting black screen.

Or I start app, scene loading after splash scene. Then i close me app with home button and i am trying re open my application after splash screen i am getting black screen.

following code from my game activity :

```
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback)
        throws IOException {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f,
            new ITimerCallback() {
                public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);

                    String rstPhoneStorage = PhoneStorage
                            .ReadFromPhoneStorage(
                                    resourcesManager.activity, "e");
                    String rstVerification = PhoneStorage
                            .ReadFromPhoneStorage(
                                    resourcesManager.activity, "v");

                    if (rstPhoneStorage != null && rstPhoneStorage != "") {
                        if (rstVerification != null
                                && rstVerification != "") {
                            SceneManager.getInstance()
                                    .createMainMenuScene();
                        } else

                            SceneManager.getInstance()
                                    .loadUnlockCodeSceneAfterWaitingCode(mEngine);


                    } else
                        SceneManager.getInstance()
                                .createRegisterMenuScene();

                }
            }));
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```

what is the problem ?

regards.

Comment: is it constant black screen or black screen for some time and display comes back?

Comment: black screen constant.

Comment: have you tried the logs? What does the logs say? And skip the splash screen try showing the main scene. when onPause method is called all resources are unloaded and onResume they are loaded again. You need to check the code of yours

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you are exiting the game on back button press then Try adding this Override method:

```
@Override
public void onBackKeyPressed() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Probably your game isn't exiting properly. Also you should dispose the previous scene and all it's child entities while changing from one scene to another.